# Sorting Table within Ember.js

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have a table generated with data from the server. Each column on the table has a button at the top to sort the entire table from high to low or low to high based on the vales in that column. There is also a name column which sorts alphabetically.

Currently I have all this hooked up with handlebars, and when you click the button, it sorts an array of table-data, and then re-interpolates the template and inserts it to the page.

I am trying to move this over to using ember.js. My first issue is that the my table-data array is not a simple array anymore, its an ember object with all kinds of get and set methods and other stuff inside. How can I sort this using a function like the one I have:

```
function sortAtoZ(arr, one, two) {
    arr.sort(function(a, b) {return a[one].localeCompare(b[two])});
}
```

Comment: http://www.estellamadison.com/?utm_source=Ember+Weekly&utm_campaign=b61e8568dd-Ember_Weekly_Issue_15&utm_medium=email&utm_term=0_e96229d21d-b61e8568dd-92242625#/posts/7729704464532575256 ... This may help you too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Support for basic sorting is built into ember array controllers via the [Sortable Mixin](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.SortableMixin.html). Out-of-box it supports sorting by one or more properties using Ember.compare but can use a custom sortFunction like:

```
App.TableController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  sortProperties: ['trackNumber'],
  sortAscending: true,
  sortFunction: function(a,b) {
    // your custom sort logic here
    // return 0 if the two parameters are equal, return a negative value if the first parameter is smaller than the second or return a positive value otherwise
  }
});
```

Also if you want to do something more advanced with tables, have a look at [ember-table](http://addepar.github.io/ember-table/)

Comment: The problem with ember-table is, as far as I see in their docs, that it doesn't have any search facilities. What can you do when you have a dataset of, let's say, 1M rows? You can't even do Ctrl+F due to the way it's rendered into the viewport...